# Is it possible to implement this version of matrix multiplication using Numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, numba

I am looking to quickly evaluate the function below, which at a high level resembles matrix multiplication. For large matrices, the below implementation is orders of magnitude slower than numpy multiplication of the matrices, leading me to believe there is better way to implement this using numpy. Is there any way to implement this using numpy functions instead of for loops? The matrices I am working with have in the range of 10K-100K elements in each dimension, so this optimization is greatly needed.

One approach is to use a 3D numpy array but this proves too large to store. I also looked into np.vectorize which does not seem to be suitable.

Thank you very much for your guidance.

**Edit: Thank you everyone for your fantastic insight and answers. Greatly appreciate the input. Moving the log outside of the loop greatly improves runtime, and it is interesting to see that the `k` lookups are significant. I have a follow-up if I may: can you see a way to speedup if the inner loop expression becomes `C[i,j] += A[i,k] * np.log(A[i,k] + B[k,j])`? The log can be moved outside as before, but only if `A[i,k]` is exponentiated, which is expensive and eliminates the gains from moving out the log.**

```
import numpy as np
import numba
from numba import njit, prange

@numba.jit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def f(A, B):
    
    C = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))

    for i in prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in prange(B.shape[1]):
            for k in prange(A.shape[1]):
                
                C[i,j] += np.log(A[i,k] + B[k,j])
                #matrix mult. would be: C[i,j] += A[i,k] * B[k,j]

    return C

#A = np.random.rand(100000, 100000)
#B = np.random.rand(100000, 100000)
#f(A, B)
```

Comment: What are relevant sizes of the input matrix? There is a significant speedup possible with a algebraic reformulation, but this can significantly decrease precision of the result. How import is precision?

Comment: Each dimensions is on the order of 10K-100K. Precision is not so important and it would be great to hear if you have an idea for a fast approximation.

Comment: This is huge. Only to make sure:  In both matrices both dimensions are 10-100k right? I will update my answer with a blocked-algorithm (Can take some time) It would also be good to write this information into your question. eg A=np.random.rand(10000,100000). This is a very important information. (small matrices are quite a lot simpler)

Comment: Yes, that is correct and will add that information to the question. Thanks for your help! By the way, I revised my question to also include a different inner loop expression, in case relevant for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since `log(a) + log(b) == log(a * b)`, you can save a lot of logarithm computations by replacing the additions by multiplications and doing the logarithm only at the end, which should save you a lot of time.

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def f(A, B):
    C = np.ones((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]), A.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(B.shape[1]):
            # Accumulate product
            for k in nb.prange(A.shape[1]):
                C[i,j] *= (A[i,k] + B[k,j])
    # Apply logarithm at the end
    return np.log(C)

# For comparison
@nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def f_orig(A, B):
    C = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]), A.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(B.shape[1]):
            for k in nb.prange(A.shape[1]):
                C[i,j] += np.log(A[i,k] + B[k,j])
    return C

# Test
np.random.seed(0)
a, b = np.random.random((1000, 100)), np.random.random((100, 2000))
print(np.allclose(f(a, b), f_orig(a, b)))
# True
%timeit f(a, b)
# 36.2 ms ± 2.91 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit f_orig(a, b)
# 296 ms ± 3.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Does it improve by doing the auxiliary variable `v *= ...` trick from your comment above?

Comment: @Jeronimo I removed it because I didn't see any difference... I had some case some time ago where it did make a difference, but I'm thinking maybe it was not exactly the same thing, it was something about [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) but I don't think that applies here.

Comment: Alright thanks for testing, made me curious since this should save another `k` address lookups per element of C, which is a lot for big A and B.

Answer (score 2):

As @jdehesa already pointed out you can use the following simplification: `log(a) + log(b) == log(a * b)` But be aware that the results can differ quite a bit.
Additionally there are many ways to optimize this function. The best solution depends on the size of the input matrices and the desired numerical stability.

**Using a scalar and work on the transposed array (automatic SIMD-vectorization possible)**

```
import numpy as np

#from version 0.43 until 0.47 this has to be set before importing numba
#Bug: https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/4689
from llvmlite import binding
binding.set_option('SVML', '-vector-library=SVML')
import numba as nb

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def f_orig(A, B):
    C = np.zeros((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))

    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(B.shape[1]):
            for k in range(A.shape[1]):
                C[i,j] += np.log(A[i,k] + B[k,j])
                #matrix mult. would be: C[i,j] += A[i,k] * B[k,j]

    return C

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def f_pre_opt(A, B):
    C = np.empty((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]))
    B_T=np.ascontiguousarray(B.T)

    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in range(B_T.shape[0]):
            acc=1.
            for k in range(A.shape[1]):
                acc*=(A[i,k] + B_T[j,k])
            C[i,j] = np.log(acc)

    return C

@nb.njit(fastmath=True, parallel=True)
def f_jdehesa(A, B):
    C = np.ones((A.shape[0], B.shape[1]), A.dtype)
    for i in nb.prange(A.shape[0]):
        for j in nb.prange(B.shape[1]):
            # Accumulate product
            for k in nb.prange(A.shape[1]):
                C[i,j] *= (A[i,k] + B[k,j])
    # Apply logarithm at the end
    return np.log(C)
```

**Timings**

```
# Test
np.random.seed(0)
a, b = np.random.random((1000, 100)), np.random.random((100, 2000))

res_1=f_orig(a, b)
res_2=f_pre_opt(a, b)
res_3=f_jdehesa(a, b)

# True
%timeit f_orig(a, b)
#262 ms ± 1.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit f_pre_opt(a, b)
#12.4 ms ± 405 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit f_jdehesa(a, b)
#41 ms ± 2.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

For larger matrices this solution is far from optimal. For a better cache usage additional optimizations like computing the result block-wise are necessary.

[Real world implementation of a matrix-matrix multiplication](https://gist.github.com/nadavrot/5b35d44e8ba3dd718e595e40184d03f0)